# Elasticsearch: group into buckets, reduce to one document per bucket, group these documents

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm looking for a way how to compute the bounce rate of webpages with elastic search.

We collect data in the following simplified structure

```
{"id":"1", "timestamp"="2017-01-25:15:23", "sessionid"="s1", "page"="index"}
{"id":"2", "timestamp"="2017-01-25:15:24", "sessionid"="s1", "page"="checkout"}
{"id":"3", "timestamp"="2017-01-25:15:25", "sessionid"="s1", "page"="confirm"}

{"id":"4", "timestamp"="2017-01-25:15:26", "sessionid"="s2", "page"="index"}
{"id":"5", "timestamp"="2017-01-25:15:27", "sessionid"="s2", "page"="checkout"}

{"id":"6", "timestamp"="2017-01-25:15:26", "sessionid"="s3", "page"="product_a"}
{"id":"7", "timestamp"="2017-01-25:15:28", "sessionid"="s3", "page"="checkout"}
```

For this sample the result of the analysis should be:

> 2/3 of the users get lost at the checkout page.
>
> 1/3 of the users get lost at the confirm page

More formally, I'm looking for a generic approach how to implement the following algorithm in an elastic query:

1. group documents by a field
2. sort each group (bucket) by a second field and reduce to the topmost document
3. group all these remaining documents by a third field
4. sort groups by number of documents

My first attempt was to solve this with a *terms aggregation* followed by a *top_hits aggregation* and finally use a
*terms_pipeline aggregation* to group the pages.

(simplified aggregation structure)

```
aggs
    terms
        field: sessionid
        aggs
            top_hits
                sort:timestamp desc
                size: 1
    terms_pipeline
        bucket_path: terms>top_hits
        field: page
```

... but unfortunately there is no such thing like a *terms_pipeline aggregation*. My bad.

Any ideas for an alternative approach?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I misunderstood something but if you are willing to know where your users are bouncing, since all pages are in a sequence, you could simply have a `terms` aggregation on the `page` field (to know which pages were visited) and a `cardinality`one on the `sessionid` field (to know how many different unique sessions you have). In this case, `cardinality(sessionid)` would yield 3.

Then again, since all pages are in a sequence, I think you don't really need to know what happened within a given session.

In your example, from the `terms(page)` aggregation, you'd know that 3 users landed on the checkout page but only one went to the confirm one. Using the cardinality of the sessions, this implicitly means that 2 users (3 total sessions - 1 confirm page hit) bounced on the checkout page.

Comment: Thanks. I think this would work for the simplified example but the example was just meant for illustration.  I'm looking for a more generic approach how to implement the algorithm in an elastic query (if possible). I edited the question to clarify this.

Comment: Then since `top_hits` is a metric aggregation, you cannot further aggregate on that data. The only way to achieve what you need is to do it in two passes, i.e. first collect the ids of the documents in your top_hits results and then in a second query filter by those ids and group by the third field.

Comment: Sorry Val for the slow response. When you are talking about "two passes" you propose to fetch the data into our app and build the second query there? Do I understand you correctly? I think your suggestion will work perfectly, as long as data volume is moderate. Unfortunately we need to process volumes that may not fit into the memory of our app. And our rational to use Elastic is to keep the big data over there. Not here :) If we go with a two pass solution, both passes should happen in Elastic. I'm currently thinking about how to mark all "last pages" of a session in advance...

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean, although the first pass will only get you the ids of the documents you need, not the full document source. Anyway, if you wish to let ES deal with the bulk of the work (which makes sense), then you need to think beforehand on how you want to index your data in order to support your use case(s). In your case, you might want to have a parent document for each session and then child documents for each event in that session. You could then easily retrieve the last event per session and then aggregate on the `page` field.